# How do I improve listening to English conversations?

Tags: listening

I am keen on learning how to listen to conversations in English through the BBC learning site. However, I'm not sure how to improve my listening ability. Please help me with a few tips and pointers for the same. Any input from similar experiences will be deeply appreciated.

So far, I just download one script and one voice stream at a time from the BBC site, then I just listen to them. No other exclusive listening activity are practiced at present.

Thanks

Comment: Try to listen to stuff that's relatively easy.  Use English subtitles so you can read along.  Listen to It over and over until you feel like you can understand, then turn off the subtitles and listen again. Once you can get the whole thing without the aid of subtitles, repeat the process for something new.  Just stick with it every day and you can make a lot of progress.  Only move on to harder things once you feel you've mastered easier things.

Comment: Are you asking about [this site](http://www.bbc.co.uk/learning/subjects/english.shtml)? One of the resources in particular? Are you just wondering generally how to efficiently improve English listening? Please [edit your question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/38728/edit) and write more, perhaps using different words. The sentence “But I have no idea what How do i make efficiency in English listening?” seems especially unclear to me. Is there another way to say what you want?

Comment: @Snailboat's "subtitles" is a good idea, but often they'll either accompany speech which is inherently difficult, or will contain transcription errors. Counter-intuitively, it may be easier to attune to *standard/clearly enunciated* English on global news sites like [RT](http://rt.com/news/) or [Aljazeera](http://www.aljazeera.com/) - I suspect that unlike most BBC broadcasts, those sites fully expect much of their target audience not to be native speakers.

Comment: I know someone who did this with a first season DVD box set of *Heroes*, and it made a world of difference for them.  It shouldn't be too hard to find something you enjoy with subtitles available.

Answer (score 1):

I basically learned English from cartoons when I was a toddler. The vocabulary was appropriate for my level and I just picked up things really easily that way. Maybe you could listen to something that interests you, find educational videos on different subjects, or watch movies in English with subtitles at first. I think having fun while learning will make it a great deal more efficient.

Comment: Thanks but your answer is very general pattern. Actually, I didn't take any efficiency like your way. But Thanks.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but your question is very general as well...I'm not sure what you mean by 'I didn't take any efficiency like your way'.

Comment: If it worked for you I suppose I shouldn't really argue. But thinking of *today's* "adult-oriented" cartoons (Family Guy, American Dad, etc.), I'd say that whereas they're excellent in terms of idiomatic usages and creative wordplay, They're not at all representative of "normal speech". Who wants to sound like today's equivalent of Donald Duck?